# Not able to use schemacrawler.

Tags: java, oracle, bash, unix, schemacrawler

I have followed this link, http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/bundled.html

I am using Oracle 11g database,

As per the doc I have downloaded the bundle for Oracle and downloaded the ojdbc driver for it (ojdbc.6.jar) and placed it in the lib folder,
then fired the command:-

```
-host=xxx -port=xxx -database=xxx -user=xxx -password=xxx
```

But its not working.

For unix its throwing error:-

```
-bash: -host=xxx: command not found
```

When I fire the command:-

```
java -classpath lib/*:. schemacrawler.tools.oracle.Main $* -host=xxx -port=xxx -database=xxx -user=xxx  -password=xxx
```

It throws the error:-

```
schemacrawler.schemacrawler.SchemaCrawlerException: No command specified
    at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.<init>(SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.java:88)
    at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.<init>(SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.java:62)
    at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerMain.main(SchemaCrawlerMain.java:76)
    at schemacrawler.tools.oracle.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

Please help to resolve

Answer (score 0):

To get help on how to use SchemaCrawler for Oracle, please use the following command:

```
java -classpath lib/*:. schemacrawler.tools.oracle.Main
```

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler